# compass-rails isn't letting me do @import compass/reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

I'm getting this error when I start my application:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.
Load path: /Users/nbenes/projects/lawgical_admin
  (in /Users/nbenes/projects/lawgical_admin/app/assets/stylesheets/screen.css.sass)
```

(stacktrace:)

```
app/assets/stylesheets/screen.css.sass:2
app/views/layouts/login.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_layouts_login_html_haml__1550030126632827390_2194381580'
```

The file that's raising the error starts like this:

`app/assets/screen.css.sass`

```
// This import applies a global reset to any page that imports this stylesheet.
@import compass/reset
```

It's crashing on that `import` line and I am not sure how to get it to see the compass gem.

My gemfile has this:

`Gemfile`

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
end
```

Compass configuration is barebones:

`config/compass.rb`

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
project_type = :rails
```

And finally, the stylesheet gets pulled into the view:

`app/views/layouts/login.html.haml`

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'screen', :media => 'screen, projection'
```

Somehow it's just not seeing compass or importing it.  I tried skipping the `compass/reset` import but then it dies later at `@import blueprint`

For some context, I am in the process of upgrading this app to rails 3.2 and to use the asset pipeline instead of Jammit to compile assets (Jammit gem and configuration files were deleted).  Any idea what's going wrong?  :(

Comment: Have you seen this issue? https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/654 Looks like you can try removing gem 'compass-rails' from the assets group, or setting `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` to false if you're deploying on heroku

Comment: Yes I tried moving out of the assets group... but that's only an issue if you're worrying about this in a production context.  I was just trying to get things working in development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I missed a very small but very important change to `config/application.rb` when upgrading from Rails 3.0.x to Rails 3.2.x

In rails 3 there's a line that reads:

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

Which I failed to upgrade to read as follows:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)   
end
```